# how to get a "Searched CASE expression" in SQL Server 2008 to return search condition instead of result_expression

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, where-clause

I'm trying to apply conditional logic in my WHERE clause using CASE statements with a "[Searched CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" which returns an expression, but it won't work since the [WHERE clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) expects a "[Search Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" instead. See below.

How to use a "Searched CASE expression" in WHERE clause and have it return a "Search Condition" instead?"

```
WHERE
(
    --user supplies both min and max price
    CASE 
        WHEN (@MIN_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MAX_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MIN_PRICE > 0 AND @MAX_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    SOLD_PRICE BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' THEN
                            LIST_PRICE_H BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                        ELSE --Price Range
                            LOW_LIST_PRICE BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                            OR
                            LIST_PRICE_H BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                    END
            END
        --user supplies just max price
        WHEN ((@MIN_PRICE IS NULL OR @MIN_PRICE = 0) AND @MAX_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MAX_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    SOLD_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' THEN
                            SEARCH_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE
                        ELSE --Price Range
                            LOW_LIST_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE
                    END
            END
        --user supplies just min price
        WHEN ((@MAX_PRICE IS NULL OR @MAX_PRICE = 0) AND @MIN_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MIN_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    SOLD_PRICE >= @MIN_PRICE
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No'
                            SEARCH_PRICE >= @MIN_PRICE
                        ELSE --Price Range
                            LIST_PRICE_H >= @MIN_PRICE
                    END
            END
        --else {do nothing} as no min/max prices supplied
    END
)
```

Comment: I realize this isn't optimal so better approaches are welcome. Was just trying to avoid writing a bunch of cascading queries and combining the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your boolean expressions into integers, 1 for true and 0 for false, then compare them to 1 to get a boolean again. You can do that by saying `case when EXPRESSION then 1 else 0 end`.

Something like this:

```
where 
case 
   when situation1 then
             case when condition1  then 1 
              else 0 
              end
    when situation2 then 
          case when conditon2 then 1
              else 0 end
    else 0 end
 = 1
```

In your example:

Like so:

```
WHERE
(
    --user supplies both min and max price
    CASE 
        WHEN (@MIN_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MAX_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MIN_PRICE > 0 AND @MAX_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    case when SOLD_PRICE BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' THEN
                            case when LIST_PRICE_H BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                        ELSE --Price Range
                        case when 
                            LOW_LIST_PRICE BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                            OR
                            LIST_PRICE_H BETWEEN @MIN_PRICE AND @MAX_PRICE
                            then 1 else 0 end
                    END
            END
        --user supplies just max price
        WHEN ((@MIN_PRICE IS NULL OR @MIN_PRICE = 0) AND @MAX_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MAX_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    case when SOLD_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' THEN
                            case when SEARCH_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                        ELSE --Price Range
                            case when LOW_LIST_PRICE <= @MAX_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                    END
            END
        --user supplies just min price
        WHEN ((@MAX_PRICE IS NULL OR @MAX_PRICE = 0) AND @MIN_PRICE IS NOT NULL AND @MIN_PRICE > 0) THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN
                    case when SOLD_PRICE >= @MIN_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                ELSE --Active and Contingent
                    CASE 
                        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' Then 
                            case when SEARCH_PRICE >= @MIN_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                        ELSE --Price Range
                            case when LIST_PRICE_H >= @MIN_PRICE then 1 else 0 end
                    END
            END
        --else {do nothing} as no min/max prices supplied
    END
    = 1
)
```

You will want to read this carefully for typos....

Also, note that this will not use any indexes. To make it use indexes you can break it out into unions or use temp tables.

Comment: While this does turn the CASE expression result into a search condition usable in the WHERE clause, I don't see how it helps solve the problem to the sql in question. All of the conditions return 1 leaving them indistinguishable from each other. I suppose you could assign different numbers to each conditional outcome in there, but I'm not sure how that would work at the end of the outer CASE expression.

Comment: @johntrepreneur, all of the conditionals return 1 if true and 0 if false BUT each conditional is only evaluated if the relevant branch of the outer case is true. So the outer case returns 1 if the selected conditional is true, and 0 otherwise. So just compare the expression to 1 to see if the selected conditional was true...

Comment: @johntrepreneur, I am presuming that you want to know that the correct conditional has been evaluated, yes? Not to output a string which contains the text of the conditional?

Comment: Ben, you are right as I don't need to know which conditional has been executed, just that at least one of the conditionals has a match so that, that record gets included in the result set. After all, it is a WHERE clause used to determine if the records match these criteria which I will get by applying the 1 = 1 logic above. Not sure why I didn't see this yesterday. Thanks, it's works now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should be functionally equivalent.

This assumes that the values used are of the `MONEY` data type... if not, you can adjust the min / max values used here to those for the data type being used.

```
-- First, set the min / max magic numbers for the MONEY data type.
DECLARE
    @MinMoney MONEY,
    @MaxMoney MONEY

SET @MinMoney = -922,337,203,685,477.5808
SET @MaxMoney = 922,337,203,685,477.5807


-- Then later in your query...
WHERE
(
    CASE 
        -- First, handle the "no parameters supplied scenario" by returning NULL,
        --  which will cause the following check to fail.
        WHEN @MIN_PRICE IS NULL AND @MAX_PRICE IS NULL THEN NULL

        -- Next, supply the values for the various statuses.
        WHEN LIST_STATUS = 'Sold' THEN SOLD_PRICE
        WHEN VALUE_RANGE_PRICING = 'No' THEN LIST_PRICE_H
        ELSE LOW_LIST_PRICE

    -- Lastly, check if the supplied value falls within the range.  
    -- If a value isn't supplied, convert it to either the min or max value.
    END BETWEEN 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(@MIN_PRICE, 0), @MinMoney) 
        AND ISNULL(NULLIF(@MAX_PRICE, 0), @MaxMoney)
)
```

Comment: Not bad, I like it (+1). I also like that you condensed it quite a bit based on all the similar logic, however you didn't solve for the one **OR** condition in the first of the three main blocks under the first --Price Range section. Yours just says "ELSE LOW_LIST_PRICE" when the original logic was either LOW_LIST_PRICE OR LIST_PRICE_H yields a match. How to handle that?